# How much vegetation is represented by the green on USGS 7.5 minute topo maps?

Tags: united-states, topographical-maps

On official USGS topo maps, vegetation is represented by green, and non vegetation by white as you can see below.

[image]

**How much vegetation does an area need to be colored green?** Are short bushes enough or does it require trees?

Comment: In reality, of course, what you find varies quite a bit since most maps are quite old and things have changed (sometimes a lot) since then.

Answer (score 5):

> Vegetation is recorded
>   when it exceeds 20% cover of the landscape for an area greater than one acre
>   (0.4 ha), and 6 ft (2 m) or more in height - tall enough to conceal troops or
>   fugitives - with the same consideration for clearings within vegetated areas.

[USGS Topographic Maps](http://www.fsl.orst.edu/pnwerc/wrb/Atlas_web_compressed/Appendices/b.USGStopo_web.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [USGS pamphlet](https://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/TopographicMapSymbols/topomapsymbols.pdf) (last page, bottom right), solid green is "Forest".  [This link](https://www1.usgs.gov/csas/nvcs/nvcsGetUnitDetails?elementGlobalId=860217) gives us

> The mesomorphic tree canopy is typically >10% cover and often exceeds 5 m in height

(I was not able to find a good reference for a definition to "Shrubland" for the spotted irregular green to get a second notion of how green is used.)

In the map you have given us, I assume that the vast majority of the ecosystems in the green fall under the forest definition.  Since your map doesn't have a key, I have to assume they are referencing the solid green as a standard.

Comment: Interesting that two different sources linked to the USGS would provide slightly different answers...